# Can vba (excel) run two 'copy' commands at the same time?

Tags: excel, vba

VBA excel in Windows 10.

I have a routine that copies and indeterminate number of files from on folder to several other folders. This works well but waits for one copy process to complete before starting another.

The line I am useing to invoke the copy ptocess is -

> FSO.CopyFile Source:=b, Destination:=ToPath

Where 'b' is the source folder and 'Topath' is one of the destination folders.

If I copy files using 'File Manager', I can run several copy processes in parallel with a vast saving in time. Is it possible to use VBA to start multiple copy processes to run at the same time?

Rob

Answer (score 1):

My idea would be to use Wscript like that

```
Sub testWscript()
    Dim wsh As New WshShell
    Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = False
    Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 1
    
    Dim f1 As String, f2 As String
    f2 = "d:\tmp"
    
    f1 = "d:\Temp\sampleDir\*.*"
    wsh.Run "cmd /K xcopy /S/E " & f1 & " " & f2, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
        
    f1 = "d:\Temp\samplefile1.jpg"
    wsh.Run "cmd /K copy " & f1 & " " & f2, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
    
    f1 = "d:\Temp\samplefiel2.jpg"
    wsh.Run "cmd /K copy " & f1 & " " & f2, windowStyle, waitOnReturn
End Sub
```

By setting `waitOnReturn = False` VBA will not wait for the copy process to complete. But you will also not get any information whether the copy process was successful or nor. If that is sufficient for you this migt be a way for you to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Public Sub CopyFileWithCmd(strSource As String, strDestination As String, Optional blnExit = True)
    Dim strCommand As String: strCommand = "cmd /c copy """ & strSource & """ """ & strDestination & """"
    Shell strCommand, vbHide
End Sub
```

You can call it like:

```
CopyFileWithCmd Source:=b, Destination:=ToPath
```

This will use a command window for the copy. If you want to keep the command open after the command is run (e.g. for debugging), replace `/c` with `/k`, and `vbHide` either with `vbNormalFocus` (the command window will get the focus) or `vbNormalNoFocus` (the command window will not get the focus). In this case, however, you will have to manually close the command window.